# Scoped Regions and View discovery

Tags: prism, prism-4

I have a fairly large prism app and am trying to app a new feature. The feature is a serial port parameter selection.

I want to refresh the list of serial port names when my viewmodel's `IsActive` property is set to `true`. This is happily achieved in a sample but reality is...different.

The view i am modifying is contained in an `ItemsControl` (marked as `"SettingsRegion"`) which is contained in a parent region ( marked as `"PageRegion"`). Settings region contains settings views from other modules.

I want to use the `SyncActiveAwareAttribute` for this but it requires scoped regions.

Do I need to use view injection (`regionmanager.Regions["blahblah"].Add(....`) here or can i get it working using view discovery (`regionManager.RegisterWithRegion(...`)?

**If I have to use injection...**

Given that the other modules would need a reference to the scoped `IRegionManager` instance in order to inject their views:

1. how is the best way to get the region manager to the other modules?
2. when should injection take place to ensure that the region exists?
3. can i mix-and-match injection with discovery? I want to avoid a big refactor.

Answer (score 3):

In order to create **Scoped Regions**, you would need to use View injection. Related information can be found in the following **MSDN Prism Chapter #7** links:

- [When to Use View Discovery vs. View Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec28)
- [Creating Multiple Instances of a Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec42)

The **Scoped Region Manager** is returned by setting the **createScopeRegionManager** overloaded parameter as *true* on the ***Region.Add()*** method. You would perform this action in the same place you usually add or register **Views** into **Regions** like on the corresponding Module's ***initialize()*** method:

```
IRegionManager scopedRegionManager = scopedRegion.Add(view, null, createScopeRegionManager);
```

Then, one possible way of sharing the **scopedRegionManager** to other modules would be to ***Publish()*** an event with the **scopedRegionManager** as a parameter. However, you should be careful with Module dependencies and the Modules instantiation order.
Another approach would be to store the **scopedRegionManager** into for example, a ***Dictionary***. You can find more related information in the following **CodePlex** thread:

- [Scoped Regions in TabControls](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/279224)

It should not be any problem by using **View Discovery** on other **Views** registration that would not present **Scoped Regions**.

I hope this helped you,

Regards.